# How can I filter object by child list property?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter the main object by it's child list property, imagine I have two class as follow:

```
class A
{
   public List<B> Bs{get;set;}
}

class B 
{

   public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

Then have instance of A that it has 10 instance of B as property. Then I want to return A object with property which the Date is greater than Date.Now.

Just should mention I want to do it for dynamic object, so I can not create code specifically for object A & B. I want to have Expression object that apply on object A then filter Bs list.

```
/// Soemthing like this
A Filter(A a, Func<A,bool> expr)
{
   return expr.Invoke(A);
}
```

Hopefully it would be clear.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to filter objects of type `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

If I've undersood the issue correctly, I'd try something like this:

```
A Filter(A a, Func<B, bool> expr)
{
    return new A {Bs = a.Bs.Where(expr).ToList()};
}
```

**Edit:** Since I've tried to comprehend the issue, I've got to propose:

```
public A Filter(A a, Func<A, Func<B, bool>, A> expr, Func<B, bool> selector)
{
    return expr.Invoke(a, selector);
}
```

And invoke this as:

```
Filter(new A(), (a, func) => new A {Bs = a.Bs.Where(func).ToList()}, b => b.Date > DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: thanks, but its not my answer, I want invoke expr on A object not on Bs property.

Comment: expr should be like Func<A, bool> not B

Comment: @Peyman last type parameter in `Func` could not be `bool`, because you are considering to return its invocation result in the `Filter` method.

Comment: I know just I put it to clear what I'm looking for. It's hard to explain it

Answer (score 0):

Use Where

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            var results = a.Bs.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(30));
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned in my question I want to invoke this condition based on A object not B, also do dynamically like Invoke method